# MapKit multiple pins same coordinates, different info selection

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit, tap

I have the following situation:
- 3 pins with same coordinates but different title and info
- on map there is ony one pin

It is possible to tap multiple times on that pin and the annotation displayed to be:
- first tap -> the annotation for pin 1
- second tap -> the annotation for pin 2
- third tap -> the annotation for pin 3
- fourth tap -> the annotation for pin 1

Do you have any ideas how should I implement it?

Comment: You explain the way it works now - tap multiple times to cycle through callouts - but not how you would like it to work. It's hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: If there are 3 or more pins dropped on map with same coordinates, when I tap multiple times only 2 of them are displayed in that bubble callout. So, in this case I want to display 3 or more different callouts information.

Comment: Nevan can u please give some advices?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the `didSelectAnnotationView` delegate method and select the "correct" annotation yourself depending on what the last "correct" selection was.

If you *only* have these annotations on the map and *only* one cluster of them, then you can keep one `int` ivar that remembers what the last selected annotation was and increment it in the delegate method.

For example:

```
// In .h
int lastAnnotationSelected;

// In .m
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    int nextAnnotationToSelect = (lastAnnotationSelected + 1) 
                                     % mapView.annotations.count;

    id<MKAnnotation> nextAnnotation =
        [mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:nextAnnotationToSelect];

    [mapView selectAnnotation:nextAnnotation animated:YES];

    lastAnnotationSelected = nextAnnotationToSelect;
}
```

If you also have `showsUserLocation` turned on, then you'll have to add a check for `MKUserLocation` in that method and skip it (if you want to) and go to the next annotation in the cluster.

Also, if you have multiple clusters of annotations (3 at coordinate A, 5 at coordinate B, 4 at coordinate C, etc), then you'll need to keep track of an array of lastAnnotationSelected ints and in the method, first determine what cluster was selected and get the next annotation to select in that cluster.